# Eclipse CDT - Keyboard shortcuts or plugins for creating new Classes and methods from compile errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-cdt

Do you know of any keyboard shortcut for Eclipse CDT like the J2EE version of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> + "New Class"?

I'm very used to Eclipse for J2EE where you can type the name of the new class you want to create right in your code, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> + "New Class" + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and that's it.

In Eclipse CDT, I have to manually create source and header files, or manually use the new class dialog/wizard, where no fields are pre-populated with any value.

The same goes for creating new methods, where you can type the method invocation and create it if it does not exist. I find it very useful for a "TDD" approach.

Thanks!

Comment: or perhaps, more generally, a way to customize the options given by the content assist?

Answer (score 0):

Probably no the answer you are looking for but in CDT currently (mars) there is no quick fix for creating new class. The best I can come up with is to define custom binding for New Class command (Window->Preferences ... type Keys .. type New and find New Class), define lets say Ctrl+4 to create new class. Then in the code double click on the class name, lets say MyClass and now press Ctrl+4, it will populate the class name (but not the file and header file names).
Send a bug to CDT if not already sent, it should be easy to add.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that possibility, thanks anyway :)

Comment: I fixed it in for Neon (added a quick fix for Type not found error), will be available in M6 milestone build.